# Custom Tag Input VueJS and Checkbox

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm working on a feature using Laravel and VueJS, [image]

In photo you can see in right hand side there have two checkbox group: 1. Size and 2. Color. And left sizde Input Tag Text Area or Text Box. If I click on checkbox Size: S it will show in tag input box like: size:S X , and if I select Color:Red , it will also show in Tag input box like: Color:Red x,At the same time two different josn object will fill with those selected checkbox. 
Like: size_object: { name:s, id: 2 }
And Color: { name:Red, id: 10 }

Can any one please tell me how can I solve this using Vuejs.

Code from comment:

```
<div v-for="size in size_lists"> 
  <input type="checkbox" 
         v-model="size_tag_lists" 
        :id="size.id" 
        :value="size.id" 
        class="attributes-checkbox" />

  {{size.name}} 
</div> 

<script> 
  data(){ return{ size_tag_lists: [] } } 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you actually written any code?

Comment: Not yet, because confused how should I start.

Comment: Seems fairly simple, define the objects for the groups, start writing the html, use v-for loops for each checkbox group...  There should be plenty of examples to help you get started online.

Comment: You should give it a try to implement it (maybe a quick fiddle) and then come back with the occuring errors (if you have any)

Comment: Hello,
I managed to do first part of this problem:
Generate checklist using vuejs and selected items stored in Object where code is below: 
HTML:
<div v-for="size in size_lists">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="size_tag_lists" :id="size.id" :value="size.id" 
    class="attributes-checkbox" />{{size.name}}
</div>

<script>
data(){
            return{
                size_tag_lists:  []
            }
}
</script>
but problem is can't find the way to show selected items in TagInputList. Can anyone please help me to do that?

Comment: Hello,
 @FrankProvost  Can you please help me to sole this problem?

Comment: I think you did not add your full code (I've added your  comment to the question in order to have formatting) can you provide a js fiddle of your full approach? You loop through size_lists, but dont show your size_list for example. Where and how do you want to show your size_tag_list?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to solve the issue by changing little bit of my architectural view of this software tools. New architectural view is like:
[image]

In this picture I kept input tags field as a self input tags, i.e 
Shoe Size: Input Tag Filed, if user click on this field listed values will appear as a drop-down list and selected one will show as a input tag in this field as well. At the same time Json object will generate with selected values like:
shoe_size_object:{ id: 2, value: 43 }. And I solved it using vue-multiselect package by following this link: https://vue-multiselect.js.org.